# Disable GLSL compiler optimization

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am using OpenGL 4.2 with GLSL 420 .I need to prevent the GLSL compiler from optimizing out unused uniforms as those serve for occasional tests.
I have tried to put:

```
#version 420
#pragma optimize (off)
...
......
```

But it seems to have no effect.The compiler still cleans all the unused uniforms.I am running on NVidia drivers v319 on Linux with GeForce 680GTX

Comment: the optimization is rigorous enough to ensure that if a uniform has a chance of being used then it won't be removed, just test for -1 when you assign the uniforms

Comment: I try not to do such test in runtime as it slows down the pipeline.But well,reading in some more places I see that #pragma doesn't work for anyone.

Comment: Why do you need this at all? Everytime you change the shader you have to relink and recompile anyway, which is allowed to change any uniform locations. And an unused uniform doesn't do any harm. `glGetUniformLocation` will return -1 for any non-found (optimized away) uniforms and `glUniform(-1, ...)` is a no-op and **not an error**. So what is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @ratchetfreak *"just test for -1 when you assign the uniforms"* - Even that isn't needed.

Comment: @ChristianRau I will explain.In my framework I use a strict approach in production,that's taking care that no "junk" or dummy calls are issued on shader programs during release version.For that to happen I construct program object such a way that they hold refs only to valid uniforms.So trying to pass a uniform data with the name which is not included in the program uniform cache causes exception.But as I said,I do also all sort of tests and in't quite time consuming commenting out stuff so it would work ok in different test cases...

Comment: Btw, I found a post saying that pragma is not a part of the specification.Probably that's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Generally, that's what a `#pragma` directive is: a compiler dependent feature. Compilers that don't know how to deal with a particular `#pragma` are perfectly allowed to ignore it. And in the case of GLSL, each driver has its own shader compiler, so pragma features will be more hit and miss.

Comment: I know this thread is a year old, but I have to ask: How can someone tell if the GLSL compiler optimized out something? Is it only by enumerating/querying the program after building it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inactive uniform determination is ***not*** an optimization. It is a consequence of how unextended GLSL programs work, they are compiled and then linked together and because of this implementations know exactly which paths contribute to actual pipeline output. Some implementations are smarter about this than others and will eliminate code paths (including uniforms) across each stage of the program if it produces no output in the fragment shader/transform feedback.

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - 7.6 Uniform Variables - pp. 117

> **7.6 Uniform Variables**
>
> > Shaders can declare named uniform variables, as described in the OpenGL Shading Language Specification . A uniform is considered an active uniform if the compiler and linker determine that the uniform will actually be accessed when the executable code is executed. In cases where the compiler and linker cannot make a conclusive determination, the uniform will be considered active.

How far an implementation takes this definition of an active uniform could be considered an optimization... but the actual process of doing this is not. I have an explanation of how NV's implementation of GLSL effectively does active uniform determination [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68482/glgetuniformlocation-returns-1/68530#68530).

I mentioned unextended GLSL programs, because *Separate Shader Objects* really throws a wrench into things. Using that extension, each program may represent exactly 1 stage of the pipeline and there is no way to determine whether a uniform used in one stage actually has an affect on the final output. Going by the formal definition of an ***active*** uniform, when SSOs are used the implementation must assume that if it is used in one stage it is active.

The bottom line is, changing the optimization level is not going to change this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, probably you're right. Also I am using separate shader object