# Why do unused shader-variables/uniforms get optimized away instead of resulting in a compilation error?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently working on a typesafe shader system and it was surprisingly easy to implement until now.

I just realized that uniforms and shader inputs are getting optimized away if they are not used in the shader. This is not hard to solve but I wonder how I would handle such a case.

Now to my question:

Is there any reason why someone would want an unused shader-input/uniform in their code?

```
...
in vec2 pos;
in vec2 uv;
...
```

For example this would be of type `Shader<vec2,vec2>`, but if uv is not used it would really be `Shader<vec2>`.

Now the question is if I just generate `Shader<vec2>` or if I generate `Shader<vec2,vec2>` but then throw an compilation error because the active uniforms length (in this case 1) would be smaller then the length of types.

At the moment I would just generate `Shader<vec2>` because that is how opengl handles it, but I am wondering why.

Edit:

Okay this is going to be way more complicated than I thought. It seems that every compiler will "optimize away" unused variables differently. I thought I could just use http://docs.gl/gl4/glGetActiveUniform but then the generated types would not be deterministic which is definitely not what I want.

I probably would have to write my own parser for this. I might even decide to abandon the project now.

Comment: IIRC removing unused attributes/uniforms is an optional optimization step; the driver doesn't _have_ to do it. As for why you might want unused vars, you might want to define a common header that declares all of the standard inputs and uniforms, though the actual shader might not use all of them.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Is it possible to turn of the optimization step? Edit: Nvm it's not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016310/disable-glsl-compiler-optimization

Comment: It would be impossible for unused uniforms to generate a compiler error, whether a uniform is used or not can only be determined at link-time. But if you think about it, even in C if you don't use a variable, that never generates a compiler error - depending on the verbosity you chose it might generate a warning, but never an outright error.